# Spring Cloud Config (Server) Monitor does not send events to clients via RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I'm using `Spring Boot / 2.1.0.RELAESE` and `Spring Cloud Dependencies / Greenwich.M3`, consider the following projects, with the following dependencies:

- https://github.com/dnijssen/configuration
- https://github.com/dnijssen/configurationclient, dependencies:

  - `spring-boot-starter-actuator`
  - `spring-boot-starter-web`
  - `spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp`
  - `spring-cloud-starter-config`
- https://github.com/dnijssen/configurationserver, dependencies:

  - `spring-boot-starter-actuator`
  - `spring-cloud-config-monitor`
  - `spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit`
  - `spring-cloud-config-server`

So my `configurationserver` fetches the properties for the `configurationclient` via a Git repository (namely https://github.com/dnijssen/configuration), when a change is made I'll trigger the `/monitor` endpoint on my `configurationserver` manually (just for testing).  Which is supposed to send an event via RabbitMQ which I started up with the following Docker command:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

This gives me the following response: `["*"]`

With the following console output on my `configurationserver`:

```
2018-11-22 09:19:48.527  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] o.s.c.c.monitor.PropertyPathEndpoint     : Refresh for: *
2018-11-22 09:19:48.543  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2018-11-22 09:19:48.550  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory.publisher#79a8318:0/SimpleConnection@34a9bacb [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55205]
2018-11-22 09:19:48.553  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (springCloudBusInput.anonymous.cT0DOhixRX6H82A1zBDF9g) durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2018-11-22 09:19:48.880  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$135b8961] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-11-22 09:19:49.162  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-22 09:19:49.165  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 0.6 seconds (JVM running for 29.712)
2018-11-22 09:19:49.228  INFO 19316 --- [nio-8888-exec-6] o.s.cloud.bus.event.RefreshListener      : Received remote refresh request. Keys refreshed []
```

However my `configurationclient` does not seem to receive any event, and is thus not refreshing itself.

What am I missing here?

Kind regards,

Dennis Nijssen

Comment: Looking at this. It is a potential bug.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus/issues/139 there was a change in behavior in stream that needed to be accounted for.

Comment: Thank you for your response, hoping to see it fixed in 2.1.0.RC1

Comment: It is already fixed and will be in RC1